# Nombres de variables con identificadores de otras variables

Tags: c, variables

Viendo el tutorial de C de tutorialspoint me encontré el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define tokenpaster(n) printf ("token" #n " = %d", token##n)

int main(void) {
   int token34 = 40;
   tokenpaster(34);
   return 0;
}
```

Y entonces me pregunté: ¿Y porque no creo variables cuyos nombres sean valores de otras variables?
La pregunta no se entiende muy bien, pero mi intento por responderla si:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++)
    {
        variable##contador = contador;
    }

    for(contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", variable##contador);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Ese código no compila bien, pero sé que debe haber una forma de lograr mi objetivo...

Comment: Para eso se inventaron los punteros ...

Comment: Pero cómo? Perdón si soy ignorante pero no soy capaz de hacer eso con punteros jaja.

Comment: No puedes crear nombres de variables "en tiempo de ejecución", porque C es un lenguaje compilado. El ejemplo que pones al inicio es una macro. Las macros se "expanden" en tiempo de compilación. El compilador ve ya el resultado de la expansión y por tanto la variable `token34`. Es imposible hacer lo mismo en tiempo de ejecución (por ejemplo, que el 34 lo introduzca un usuario).

Comment: Es decir que no puedo hacer de ninguna manera un programa que genere variables...

Comment: Si quieres generar una variable, usas `malloc` para reservar espacio y guardas su dirección en un puntero. Accedes a la variable usando el puntero. Si quieres tener un número indeterminado de variables, usas un arreglo de punteros.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes crear variables, pero no puedes crear _nombres_ de variables dinámicamente. Lo del `##` es interpretado por el preprocesador (paso previo a la compilación, que recibe ya el nombre concreto). Lo que puedes hacer es una variable con un nombre prefijado, pero que no tenga espacio reservado, sólo un apuntador que servirá para apuntar al dato cuando se cree (mediante `malloc()`). De este modo puedes crear el "espacio" que usarán los datos, pero no puedes crear un nombre "dinámicamente".

Comment: Lo que intentas en tu código se implementaría mediante un array. En vez de `variable##token` harías `variable[token]` para acceder a los elementos del array. Ese array puede tener un tamaño prefijado en el código (10 en este caso) si lo declaras como `int variable[10]`, o puedes darle un tamaño en tiempo de ejecución si lo declaras como puntero y usas `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define tokenpaster(n) printf ("token" #n " = %d", token##n)
```

Esto es una macro, la macro recibe un único parámetro `n` y con ese parámetro genera la siguiente línea de código:

```
printf("token" #n " = %d", token##n)
```

Donde:

- `#n` convierte a `string` el valor asignado a `n`
- `##n` concatena el valor de `n` con la palabra `token`.

Así, en el ejemplo que te ponen:

```
tokenpaster(34);
```

Se genera la siguiente línea de código:

```
printf("token34 = %d", token34)
```

Dicho esto, las almohadillas no forman parte del lenguaje C. No las puedes usar en código C. El único que las interpreta es el precompilador. Esto plantea ciertas limitaciones. Efectivamente, dado que el precompilador se ejecuta antes que el compilador, el código del precompilador no se ve afectado por el código C++ (bucles, valor de las variables, ...).

De hecho, el ejemplo anterior fallaría si a la macro le pasases una variable:

```
tokenpaster(token34);
```

En este caso el código que generaría la macro sería el siguiente:

```
printf("tokentoken34 = %d", tokentoken34);
```

Ante esta entrada, el compilador generaría un error, ya que no sería capaz de encontrar la variable `tokentoken34`.

Lo lamento pero esta vía no te va a permitir conseguir tus objetivos.

Para conseguir lo que pretendes deberías implementar una función a la que le pudieses pasar variables junto con su identificador. Esta función debería recorrer el string y reemplazar los identificadores que vaya encontrando por los valores que correspondan.

Para hacer esta tarea tienes que entender cómo funcionan las funciones variádicas en C. No me voy a extender en este tema, hay bastante documentación en Internet.

Un posible y limitado ejemplo (únicamente trabaja con enteros) de cómo podría quedar la función:

```
void print(char const* string, int count, ...)
{
    struct data
    {
        char name[100];
        int value;
    };

    int totalArgs = count;
    count*=2;
    
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);

    struct data * parameters = (struct data*)malloc(totalArgs*sizeof(struct data));
    for( int i=0; i<totalArgs; i++)
    {
        strcpy(parameters[i].name, va_arg(args, char*));
        parameters[i].value = va_arg(args, int);
    }

    va_end(args);

    for( int i=0; string[i]!='\0'; ++i )
    {
        if( string[i] == '{' )
        {
            int replaced = 0;
            int j;
            for( j=i+1; string[j]!='}'; ++j );

            for( int dataIndex=0; dataIndex<totalArgs; ++dataIndex )
            {
                if( memcmp(string+i+1, parameters[dataIndex].name, j-i-1) == 0 )
                {
                    printf("%d", parameters[dataIndex].value);
                    i=j;
                    replaced = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if( !replaced )
            {
                while(i<=j)
                {
                    putchar(string[i++]);
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(string[i]);
        }
    }

    free(parameters);
}
```

Para usarla hay que facilitarle una lista con los diferentes identificadores y sus valores de reemplazo:

```
int main()
{
    int value = 123;
    print("X={X} value={value} other={other}", 2, "X", 44, "value", value);
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://ideone.com/zMFdom)